# Why is the error message for binary operators different for factors as it is for character?

Tags: r

I know and understand that operations like addition and substraction are invalid for both character class and factor class data. What I don't understand is why the behaviour of R is different for both types.

E.g.

```
#Creating character and factor
my_text<-c("This", "is", "text")
my_factor<-factor(c("This", "is", "factor"))

#This produces an error
my_text+1

#This produces "only" a warning and NA's
my_factor+1
```

I would expect a simple error in both cases. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably this comes from the fact that the functions called are not the same.

As you can read in the help page for Arithmetic Operators:

> The unary and binary arithmetic operators are generic functions: methods can be written for them individually or via the Ops group generic function

Then, if you take a look at the S3 Group Generic Functions help page, under the "Ops" paragraph, you can read:

> For each argument its vector of classes is examined to see if there is a matching specific (preferred) or Ops method. If a method is found for just one argument or the same method is found for both, it is used. If different methods are found, there is a warning about ‘incompatible methods’: in that case or if no method is found for either argument the internal method is used.

So, for `my_factor`, `Ops.factor` is called (as you can see in the warning message) and at the beginning of it, you'll find:

```
 ok <- switch(.Generic, `==` = , `!=` = TRUE, FALSE)
 if (!ok) {
     warning(gettextf("%s not meaningful for factors", sQuote(.Generic)))
     return(rep.int(NA, max(length(e1), if (!missing(e2)) length(e2))))
 }
```

which explains the result and the warning you're getting when doing `my_factor+1`

Whereas for `my_text` the internal method (`.Primitive("+")`) is called. (To see where the error message is implemented, you have to dive into the [source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/ec8db8be924cf4ffd49438cbca38b876c7931863/src/main/arithmetic.c), the message is in line 511).